# HTTP digest in javascript. md5 recalculation for new uri

Tags: javascript, http, md5, digest

I write client side javascript implementation of digest authorization and I ran into trouble. After a successful login I put authorization header parameters into cookie for the nest request. But if uri is changed md5 hash becomes invalid. I could recalculate Authorization, but I have no clear text password already. I suppose that browser implementation makes this recalculation. Am I right? If that is true what can I do? To store clear text password in variable is not good idea for security reasons.

Comment: Can't you hash by domain? You haven't really provided any technical details of your implementation.

Comment: Domain (realm) is used in hash calculation, but how it helps me? I skip  irrelevant details. What technical details are required? I saw (for native browser implementation) that `response` parameter in `Authorization` header for request to new uri differs from previous one. I supposed that browser stores clear text password and uses it in hash recalculation. My main question is: Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I found a **half** solution. `response` md5 hash is calculated as a combination of two hashes: ha1 and ha2. ha1 depends on `username`, `realm` and `password`. ha2 depends on `method` and `uri`. So I can store ha1 in the local storage of a browser and use it in `response` recalculation. This way doesn't solve the origin problem, but it makes impossible for malefactor to recalculate `response` for other `realm`s.